# AS2 - Jump to a frame of a movieclip in another frame

Tags: actionscript-2, flash, movieclip, flashdevelop

Lets say that I have 2 frames:

Frame 1 with mc01 in it (Instance name: f1)
Frame 2 with mc02 in it (Instance name: f2)

At a certain point, in mc02 (inside Frame 2), I want to jump to let's say Frame 50 of mc01, that is contained in Frame 1. How?

My code atm (that produces 0 results):

```
_root.f1.mc01.gotoAndPlay(50);
```

Remember this is an Actionscript 2 question. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the instance name, like this:

```
_root.f1.gotoAndPlay(50);
```

Also, you can just use `_parent`, if both are siblings:

```
_parent.f1.gotoAndPlay(50);
```

Please note that the mc01 (named f1) must exist on frame 2 for this to work.

#### Update:

Your problem is that, when you need to change the frame of `mc01`, it doesn't exist. So you need to store a configuration for it to access on it's initialization. For example:

`_root` frame 1:

```
// if config isn't set yet, let's define it.
var config;
if (!config) {
  config = {f1: {startFrame: 1}};
}
```

`mc01` frame 1:

```
// go to config.f1.startFrame. If no config is set, go to 1.
gotoAndPlay(_parent.config.f1.startFrame || 1);
```

`mc02` anywhere:

```
// change the config of mc01. Now, when it's created again
// it'll read the new value and jump straight to it.
_parent.config.f1.startFrame = 50;
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is not jumping to the frame of a movieclip that's in the same frame we are running the code at that moment, but jumping from, for example, mc02 of frame2 to frame 50 of mc01 that's in frame1.

Comment: Thank you! :) [notenoughchars]